# apache2.4.7 not logging "404 Not Found" pages to error.log

Tags: apache, logging, http-status-code-404

I've seen questions about how to **not** log 404 errors to the error log, this is the opposite.

For some reason my apache installation does not log 404 errors to my error log (or to my access log for that matter).  I have set the error log properly and see errors going to it, but when I access non-existent pages I simply get my 404 error - the **access** (but not the 404 error) shows up in the access.log, but I don't see anything in the error log (which makes it hard, for example, to debug *why* some pages aren't showing up).

My apache (2.4.7) conf settings regarding logs (in the order they are set) are:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn  # Though I've tried setting this to debug
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"" common
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
CustomLog logs/access_log common
LogFormat "%{HOST}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon
```

So the only ones that I think are relevant to error log (ignoring overwritten settings) are:

```
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn  # Though I've tried setting this to debug
```

Comment: Can we see your `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: I'm not using Java or log4j

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same problem. Ideas anyone? I have this in my .htaccess file: ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.php to redirect to a friendly page. Does doing this prevent any logging of 404 errors?

Comment: Small update here. I was partially wrong. The 404s are appearing in my access log, but not error log. My current suspicion is that by using an ErrorDocument handler to show a custom 404 page precludes the errors from being written to the error log. If that's the case, I'm finding it hard to find this effect documented anywhere.

Comment: I'm not using an ErrorDocument, though I could see how that would redirect the 404 from being an error.  Either way that's not the case with my setup.

Comment: Do you use a custom ErrorDocument? I had the same problem, and after disabling my ErrorDocument for 404 error, I received log in my access logfile. (Still figuring out why not in my error logfile)

Comment: No, I do not - I have the generic error 404 page, and I checked to make sure ErrorDocument is not set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 error doesn't appear in Apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568205/404-error-doesnt-appear-in-apache-error-log)

Comment: Umm.. @ToddVierling, why are you marking this question, which is answered, and from 2015, as a possible duplicate of a question someone asked in 2016 which does not have a selected answer and the top answer is not the answer for this problem?  That is completely backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

LogLevel needs to be set to something like 'info' - for some reason the LogLevel of 'warn' which use to log 404 errors no longer does so.

I don't know if 'debug' would work, my question implies that it wouldn't, but I also realized that I had LogLevel set in two places.

Answer (score 0):

Good question I'm not sure how to configure apache to do this. Usually to find my errors I just search my access log. You can do this with grep or awk.  A really basic command to try is:

```
grep ' 404 ' access.log
```

Comment: 404 not found errors are not being logged to *either* access.log or error.log (updated question)