# 404 error doesn't appear in Apache error.log

Tags: apache, logging

If a visitor gets 404 error, nothing is written in apache `error.log`. In access log it appears like this:

```
GET /qqq HTTP/1.1" 404 409 "-"
```

And nothing in `error.log`. I have tried everything about `LogLevel`. As I understand, it is because that 404 page is custom page like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /new404.html
```

But I run search through all `/etc/apache2` for text "404" in files and nothing was found there (instead of commented lines). What can be the problem? Or maybe I can somehow disable custom 404 page in `.htaccess` file? Or any other ways to display 404 errors in `error.log`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache2.4.7 not logging “404 Not Found” pages to error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324957/apache2-4-7-not-logging-404-not-found-pages-to-error-log)

Answer (score 21):

As the person who filed the [Apache bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35768) which demoted 404 from Error to Info level as of Apache 2.4.1, here's the justification:

In production HTTP servers open to the Internet, 404s happen all the time. Malware, scanner scripts, and all sorts of other things probe Web servers for vulnerabilities or just because they can, and these things would all trigger errors which will end up being logged somewhere if the appropriate error level is set.

Most production Web server admins are content with seeing 404s in their access logs (which are logged right alongside 200s and 30x redirects), and want to see real server problems -- things they have control over fixing -- in the error log. The logging of 404s in error.log can, in some servers, be so much log spam that it drowns out legitimate problems needing the administrator's attention.

404 is a *content* issue, not a *server* issue. So my recommendation is to look in your access.log (or equivalent) for them. If you really want *content* related issues logged in error.log, you need to set `LogLevel core:info`. This will give you 404s there, and a few other kinds of content-related error messages too.

Comment: This change silently broke my fail2ban rules. But I agree with you.

Comment: How can I achieve this with Apache 2.2? Is there a way to turn off loggin 404 errors in that version?

Comment: Logging 404 in error_log could help debugging a site since apache correctly logs what is the physical path it thinks the file should have. A great debugging tool was removed.

Comment: @GaborGarami, use `LogLevel core:info` as noted above if you want that data in error.log.

Answer (score 5):

404 "errors" don't normally appear in the Apache error log, regardless of whether you have a custom `ErrorDocument` defined or not.

A 404 *error* is not strictly a server error. It's an expected HTTP response, so it naturally appears in the access log (as you have stated), not in the error log. The "404" is the HTTP response code, not a server error code.

However, you should be able to enable additional "information" messages in your error logging (eg. `LogLevel info` on Apache 2.4) to get this "information" in your system error log:

```
[Mon Feb 06 08:00:00.090525 2017] [core:info] [pid 13876:tid 1748] [client 203.0.113.111:54493] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/path/to/file
```

Note, however, that there is no mention of "404" - which maybe why your searches came up blank. This LogLevel should not be maintained on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps somebody... 
I had zombie apache instances running (with a slightly different config loaded), and every other request for a static resource defined using an Alias was 404-ing.

Killed the zombies and all good...

Answer (score 0):

404 is a server response, not a error.
You can get the 404 log doing something like:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access_log | grep " 404 " | awk -F' ' '{print $4," ",$5,"-",$7}' > /root/404.log
```

and adjust the awk as you need!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are answering an old question. Posting new answers to old questions is usually done in order to renew the solutions so it will support new syntax or new versions of a specific language/library. In this case, your answer doesn't provide any additional information in comparison to what other users had already wrote. Please consider deleting it or editing it so it will contain a more comprehensive explanation.